# How to sort an alphabet of a language not presented in ISO?

Tags: python, sorting

There is a language (Circassian) which is not presented in ISO, it's based on Cyrillic characters, but have it's own order which differs from standard Cyrillic order. So there is a problem I can't solve. I need to sort words in database according to Circassian alphabet order. I need your ideas, guys, how to solve this problem, because I'm pretty sure my skills aren't good enough for this task.

Comment: what is the language? There are many circassian languages

Comment: @JohnSmith There are only two official languages, Adyghe and Kabardian, I need to sort Kabardian

Comment: Is the order for that language still lexicographical, just with a different alphabet ordering than normal? If so, you should pretty easily be able to write a `key` function for your `sort`, just convert the word string into a tuple of indexes into the alphabet.

Comment: @Blckknght, In Circassian language there is one feature, some sounds are denoted by several symbols, for example, the sound "кхъу", in the Circassian language this is considered to be one letter, not four.

Comment: What does it mean to not be presented in ISO? Google suggests the ISO639-2 language code for this language is `kbd`

Comment: @thatotherguy anyway, I can't use .sort() method to sort words in Circassian language, it will sort by Russian (Cyrillic) order.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the built-in function `.sort()` and module `locale` to sort the words. A simple example would be:

```
alphabet = ['Ж', 'Жь', 'Гъ'] # obviously the list should contain all the letters

import locale

locale.setlocale(category=locale.LC_ALL, locale="kbd")    
alphabet.sort(key=locale.strxfrm)
print(alphabet)

['Гъ', 'Ж', 'Жь']
```

Comment: Oh wow, `locale.strxfrm` looks like it's exactly what the questioner was looking for. Just `list_of_words.sort(key=locale.strxfrm)` is probably all they need (after setting the appropriate locale).

Comment: I got this error `locale.Error: unsupported locale setting`

Comment: There is no `kbd` in `locale_alias` in `locale` module.

Comment: Hm, I get that error on mac and ubuntu, but on windows I got no error, anyway it doesn't sort as required, it always put letter `Э` to the end of the list, but it's the second letter in the Kabardian alphabet.

Comment: And `locale.getlocale()` raises a `ValueError: unknown locale: kbd`

Comment: @Bootuz in your linux machine check your locales with `locale -a`, in order to find the specific code for kabardian language. It's also possible that kabardian has a different `locale_alias` in windows, since kbd didn't sort your values as you wanted. You can search for kabardian locale in python in the list of all locales, with `locale.locale_alias`

Comment: @JohnSmith, yeah I did that, but didn't find the kbd code in the ubuntu, Mac and windows, I think there is no kbd locale in that module. Perhaps it's one the ru_RUs, but I'm not sure about that, is there a way to contact with the developers of that module?